# Аяксом подтянуть список из бд и сохранить

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть две модели

```
 public class Contact
      {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Фамилия")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Имя"), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("\\+380+\\d+", ErrorMessage="Введите номер в фортмате +380ХХХХХХХХХ")]
    [Display(Name = "Телефон"), MaxLength(13), Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Фото профиля")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Название компании"), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Адрес")]
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Email раб.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("\\+380+\\d+", ErrorMessage="Введите номер в фортмате +380ХХХХХХХХХ")]
    [Display(Name = "Раб. тел."), MaxLength(13), Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Логотип компании")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

public Company()
{
    Contacts = new List<Contact>();
}
public override string ToString()
{
    return Name;
}
}
public class CRMContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public CRMContext() : base("IdentityDb")
    {}
}
```

Вьюха

```
<h2>Создание контакта</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Добавить контакт</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">Фамилия</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">Имя</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">Отчество</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">Телефон</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">E-mail</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">Фото профиля</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="uploadImage" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Создать" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Как правильно при создании контакта добавить поле(input) Компания, в которое аяксом при клике на него будет подгружаться список компаний и сохранить в бд?

Answer (score 0):

Самый распространенный вариант это использовать не поле input, а select, в который загрузится список компаний сразу же при открытии страницы. Этому полю задайте имя CompanyId. Соответственно, выбрав из получившегося выпадающего списка компаний нужную, при сабмите в контроллер уйдет модель с заполненным свойством CompanyId. А сам выпадающий список можно заполнить, передав из метода действия Create в представление заранее подгруженный из базы список компаний. Для этого нужно создать экземпляр класса SelectList, передав ему в конструкторе список компаний из БД. Затем полученный SelectList передать в словарь ViewBag.Companies. А в файле представления используйте Html.DropDownListFor для свойства CompanyId. Ему и передайте список из ViewBag.Companies. То есть, ajax можно и не использовать.

Comment: а можнол примеры кода добавить в соответствии с тем, что указал автор, то есть на основе его кода модели и представления. Спасибо

Comment: @Олег А если в бд 100к+ компаний? Не лучше ли ajaxом тянуть компании и не передавать во ViewBag все при загрузке страницы? Это же увеличит время загрузки как я понимаю

Comment: @Антон Евсеев, верно, если в базе несколько сотен компаний, то предложенный вариант не лучший. Я это предложил для решения с небольшим количеством компаний, примерно около сотни. Если уж использовать асинхронную дозагрузку списка, то самое очевидное решение это добавить метод действия, принимающий POST запрос с клиента, и возвращающий список в JSON формате.